# How to check whether the folder is empty except one subfolder

Tags: powershell

I have a scenario where the code should check for the emptiness of folder *C:\Temp*. If the *C:\Temp* folder contains subfolder "Doc" the code snippet should ignore the subfolder and check whether the *C:\Temp* is empty except "Doc"

I tried the below code snippet to check the emptiness of *C:\Temp*

```
if((Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Measure-Object).Count -eq 0){

Write-Output " C:\Temp is empty"}

else
{
Write-Output "C:\Temp is not empty"}
```

The code only checks for emptiness of *C:\temp*. How to ignore the presence of "Doc" and check for emptiness of *C:\Temp*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add other condition to exclude the Doc folder, since you already know the folder to exclude.

```
if(((Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp" -Exclude "doc" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Length) -eq 0) {Write-Output " C:\Temp is empty"} else { Write-Output "C:\Temp is not empty"}
```